# Java parsing xml file with appended data

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've xml file, which looks like this:

```
<Header>
  <Type>TestType</Type>
  <Owner>Me</Owner>
</Header>
ĺß™¸Ű;?źÉćĂˇţ¬=ńgăűßEĹ¶áCórýjąŞŢđ·I_§Ä†ÉD¤ďsĂŢŘö¤xi¦Ö†5ÚPMáx^š‡âő
```

Those funny letters are binary coded data.

I've a trouble with parsing it. All I want to do is read values of Type and Owner nodes and data after Header. That data can be big. It's basically xml with data appended after it. Header always starts with  and ends with . Number of child nodes in it can change

I tried just simple parsing:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
```

and what I got was:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried just simple parsing `DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);`

Comment: And what happened? Help us out here, we can't guess these things.

Comment: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.` happened

Comment: This is not an XML file so XML processing tools will not be able to parse it as is. You will need to state further information about the data format (e.g. is the header always four lines; does the body begin with some magic byte sequence.)

Comment: It's basically xml with data appended after it. Header always starts with <Header> and ends with </Header>. Number of child nodes in it can change.

Comment: @Mumin the comments you've made may help someone to answer the question.  You can edit your question and add the extra information to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be processed by an XML parser a file must be [**well formed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) and optionally **valid** (The latter requires testing against a "schema" describing the expected tag format).

In this case your document is not well formed:

```
$ xmllint --noout File1.xml
File1.xml:5: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
ĺß™¸Ű;?źÉćĂˇţ¬=ńgăűßEĹ¶áCórýjąŞŢđ·I_§Ä†ÉD¤ďsĂ
^
```

I would suggest finding some way to strip away the offending characters and then process the properly formatted XML. For example assuming the XML is in the first 4 files of the file:

```
head -n 4 File1.xml | xmllint --noout -
```

Comment: It's not XML file, in BNF: **document ::= prolog element Misc*** and **Misc ::= Comment | PI | S** look at spec http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Misc

Comment: @DanielKec I never claimed it was XML.... Also doesn't the prolog apply to the start of the document, not the end? ... Let's not argue the toss. The main point is that an XML parser will not process a malformed XML document :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could try a SAX parser instead which does not read in the whole document. Just read in elements/attributes until you have what you want, then stop.

But this is not a well formed XML file. If possible, fix it by putting the (encoded) binary data into its own element.